# change parameter in one direction in update function when making api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, sqlite

i'm trying to make API using Ruby on Rails 5 , i'm new on it so i used scaffold to generate tables  so this my main table for trip

```
class CreateTrips < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :trips do |t|
      t.string :nameOfDriver
      t.string :status
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my update function in controller

```
def update
  if @trip.update(trip_params)
    render json: @trip

 else
  render json: @trip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
 end
end
```

i'm trying to add constrains first, to status to be "completed " or "ongoing " ... second check if it "completed" i can't change it to "ongoing"

this link for the full project 
https://github.com/gnik2036/RubyTask

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to update the actual value, which your current code should do. I would you like to ensure that the status can't be changed improperly?

Comment: no i can update status with any string , i'm trying to add constrains first, to status to be "completed " or  "ongoing "        ... second  check if it "completed" i can't change it to "ongoing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  TRIP_STATUSES = %w[completed ongoin].freeze
  INVALID_STATUS_CHANGES = [%w[completed ongoin]].freeze
  validate :status_validity, on: :update
  validates :status, presence: true, inclusion: { in: TRIP_STATUSES }

  private

  def status_validity
    return unless status_changed?

    if INVALID_STATUS_CHANGES.include? status_change
      errors.add(:status, "Cannot be changed from #{status_was} to #{status}.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i add it to path  model/trip.rb but unfortunately give me an error and now work you can check  it on my link on githhub

Comment: @MohammedHassan Did you push your changes to GitHub? I don't see a recent commit.

Comment: sorry but i didn't i trying to describe my path in right way i'm sorry :) ,this error ArgumentError (You need to supply at least one validation):

app/models/trip.rb:4:in `<class:Trip>'
app/models/trip.rb:1:in `<main>'

Comment: also you can check my git now

Comment: Maybe its the typo I had above, try changing line 3 from `validates` to `validate`

Comment: look to this error when i change it :) ,                                                                  ArgumentError (Unknown key: :presence. Valid keys are: :on, :if, :unless, :prepend. Perhaps you meant to call `validates` instead of `validate`?):

app/models/trip.rb:5:in `<class:Trip>'
app/models/trip.rb:1:in `<main>'

Comment: Okay, I just pulled down your code and ran it. The code above should work. Copy and paste it all, I mad quite a few changes.

Comment: thank you so much , and if you have good tutorial will help me please mention it , and thank you again

Comment: For a specific topic? If you wan't to just learn rails in general I would point you to [The Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails). Or [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html)

Comment: You can also do the constraint on the database side, [here's a gem](https://github.com/nullobject/rein) to help

Comment: thank you so much , if you don't mind i have another question in my project , if i want to close the id for trip so i can't use it again after being complete in location table

Comment: in brief when trip status "complete" i can't add another location with the same id for completed  trip

Comment: I'm not completely understanding your question. The id is something that is maintained by the framework. Perhaps you should create a new question, so you can better explain it.